# Remove row base on criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some values on column A such as:

```
"A"        "B"
1           ok
1           ok
1           me
2           next
2           next
2           next
```

My code goes and and color the row on "A" if it is all the same, what i want is if column "A" have all one's to check column "B" for the last value which is "me" if it's there, leave those rows with "1" in column A alone, if it's not, delete all the rows that have "1". Not sure how to accomplish that. any help is appreciated.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim initialPlaceHolderValue As String
Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

FirstRow = UsedRng(1).Row
LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row
r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
initialPlaceHolderValue = Cells(FirstRow + 1, 1).Value
For i = FirstRow + 1 To LastRow
    myColor = RGB(r, g, b)
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = initialPlaceHolderValue Then
        Debug.Print Cells(i, 19).Value
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = myColor

    Else
        Dim myRange As Range

        initialPlaceHolderValue = Cells(i, 1).Value
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(180, 255)
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Look into `AutoFilter`, `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and `Find`

Comment: example would be great!

Comment: If you google any of those phrases you will find a slew of examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should achieve what you want (at least what I think you want, your question is not very easily understandable).

```
Sub RemoveIfNot1AndMe()
    For Each cell In Range("Your Range In Column A")
        If (cell.Value = "1") Then
            If (Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value <> "me") Then
                Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

### Explanations

The loop will go through every cell in your row (could be your column) and if the value is **1** it will check if the cell next to it contains **me** and if it doesn't delete it.

Something like

```
"A"        "B"
1           ok
1           ok
1           me
2           next
2           next
2           next
```

Will end up looking like this

```
"A"        "B"
1           ok
1           ok
2           next
2           next
2           next
```

---

### EDIT

```
Sub RemoveIfNot1AndMe()
    Dim deleteRowsWithValue1 As Boolean
    deleteRowsWithValue1 = False

    For Each cell In Range("Your range")
        If (cell.Value = "1") Then
            If (Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = "me") Then
                deleteRowsWithValue1 = True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    If (deleteRowsWithValue1) Then
        For i = 1 To Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
            If (Range("A" & i).Value = "1") Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Something like

```
"A"        "B"
1           ok
1           ok
1           me
2           next
2           next
2           next
```

Will end up looking like this

```
"A"        "B"
2           next
2           next
2           next
```

Comment: yes, but i want to remove all the rows with "1" in column A if there is no "me" on column B.

Comment: @pokemon_Man Well in this case my function works. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: it doesn't work, it needs to remove all the rows that contain "1" if column B has a value of "me"

Comment: @pokemon_Man The code above does exactly what you are describing. Do you mean removing all the row with 1 in the column A when you have one entry with 1 - me ?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean.

Comment: @pokemon_Man Please look at the function in the EDIT. This should give the result you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic, brute force approach for you:

1. Find if there is such a pair of cells: "1" in A-col and "m" in B-col
2. If Such a pair exist then look for any row with "1" in A-col and NOT "m" in B-column; WARNING: start this at the bottom of the range and look up to the top of the worksheet (otherwise deleting rows is likely to mess up your logic). Delete any such rows.
3. Redo the `LastRow = ...` bit since it will become smaller if you deleted any lines.

Do this between the `LastRow = ...` line and `r = ..." line.

Good luck and share with us your success.

And, btw, it's a good practice to declare ALL the variables if you do declare them at all (as you certainly should). Also, there is no need to declare any WITHIN a loop, over and over again, as you have done there with `myRange`; just move it to the top of the sub.

Comment: example would be great!